# Why doesn't run method call?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've write the following example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    MyThread(Runnable r){
        super(r);
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("run");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Thread t = new MyThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrruuuuuuuuuuuun");
        }
    });
    t.start(); //run
}
```

Why does run methdo defined in `MyThread` was called instead?

Comment: @practice2perfect I've written a separate class called MyThread and just import him into Main.

Comment: why isn't your main method encapsulated to a class ?

Comment: @Fev It's just a snippet of a Main class and a separated MyThread class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default behavior of a thread constructed with a Runnable is to delegate to the runnable passed as argument to the constructor. But you overrode `run()` in the thread itself, so instead of delegating to the runnable, it executes the code inside the overridden `run()` method.

For the record, here's the default implementation of Thread.run(), that you overrode:

```
private Runnable target;

public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's explaining everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because you the `MyThread.run` is not override, but the `Runnable.run` is. Now if you look at your implementation of `MyThread.run`, the stored `Runnable` plays no part in it. In other words, it doesn't matter what kind of runnable you give with the constructor. You should use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Thread t = new MyThread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrruuuuuuuuuuuun");
        }
    });
    t.start(); //run
}
```

---

As @BorisTheSpider notes, overriding a `Thread` is in general not good practice: a `Thread` has the responsibility to start a `Thread` and give control to a runnable. A better implementation would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrruuuuuuuuuuuun");
        }
    }));
    t.start(); //run
}
```

Comment: It's better practice to supply a `Runnable` to a `Thread` rather than to extend `Thread`. This separates concerns more cleanly and avoids lots of synchronization bugs that result from locking on a thread instances monitor.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I agree, but this was not really the question I guess. The question was why the inheritance principle didn't work. But you comment is constructive in a sense that it shows "good practice". I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Yes, update is good. I think your first sentence is confusing, _Because you didn't override the `MyThread.run` method but the given `Runnable.run`._ I'm not entirely sure that this is particularly clear.